# iCloud Time Out error messages in the console with core data app and iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, icloud

I have an existing app in the App Store which uses Core Data for the keeping of it's data, and iCloud to synchronise across to other devices. The app works really well in iOS 7, but on iOS 8 with Xcode 6, I'm getting the errors below:

```
-[PFUbiquitySafeSaveFile waitForFileToDownload:](489): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquityBaseline: 0x170126040>(0)
    permanentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1740bcc80>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/<iCloudDirectory>/Documents/CloudLogs/.baseline/EvyCloud/WVf0Dg3x4aqbEj~WvOz9p4_uNDY2us3DJ3aK0MihPb8=/baseline.zip
    safeLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1740bcce0>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/<iCloudDirectory>/Documents/CloudLogs/.baseline/EvyCloud/WVf0Dg3x4aqbEj~WvOz9p4_uNDY2us3DJ3aK0MihPb8=/mobile~696E1200-62F8-4258-AAB7-BB58340802A0
    currentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1740bcc80>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/<iCloudDirectory>/Documents/CloudLogs/.baseline/EvyCloud/WVf0Dg3x4aqbEj~WvOz9p4_uNDY2us3DJ3aK0MihPb8=/baseline.zip

    storeName: EvyCloud
    modelVersionHash: WVf0Dg3x4aqbEj~WvOz9p4_uNDY2us3DJ3aK0MihPb8=
    baselineArchiveLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1740bcc80>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/<iCloudDirectory>/Documents/CloudLogs/.baseline/EvyCloud/WVf0Dg3x4aqbEj~WvOz9p4_uNDY2us3DJ3aK0MihPb8=/baseline.zip

Download failed for file, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file download timed out." UserInfo=0x174463640 {NSLocalizedDescription=The file download timed out.}
```

The strange thing is that the data still gets synchronised, but these errors are clearly something I should be concerned about. These errors do not occur on iOS 7 devices.

I have seen some posts relating to the fact that these could be iCloud Server errors, but I've had this issue now for 4 weeks (I've waited to log this issue, in case it was indeed server errors).

I'm using iCloud Documents in the Capabilities Pane of Xcode and not using CloudKit.

Any guidance on this would really be appreciated.

Comment: Exactly same problem here, keep updated if you find solution. The app is not syncing old data on clean install and getting this error.

Comment: For all weird iCloud sync problems it's worth using the Settings app to sign out of your iCloud account, sign in again, and reboot your device for good measure. I'm seeing general issues with the underlying daemons not syncing documents properly (which is what iCloud Core Data sync is built on top of), and the above usually clears this. (I'm guessing it forces the daemons to go off an reevaluate what the state of the store actually is, rather than relying on some earlier, erroneous, cached conclusion). iCloud Drive accounts seem to be more ropey than Documents & Data accounts (new daemons).

Comment: Dear Harry and Rob - thanks for the replies and I agree with you Rob, it's flakey right now and I've seen rebooting on some people did help. In my case, I was nervous to enable iCloud Drive because of it's untested waters and so I signed up for another account, enabled iCloud drive and boom, the data came in with no errors and in a much quicker time. I did the same with my main account and it worked. So it seems like my users would have to be using iCloud Drive to get iCloud synching working 1) at all and 2) faster than normal. I can confirm that with other third-party apps

Comment: That I'm using, iCloud synching wasn't working. I enabled iCloud Drive and bang, everything started working, so this isn't really a technical solution, but it's one that works (for now).